# message content id in fallr plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery fallr plugin for one of my project. Can someone guide me about it?
I want to give the id of content to be shown in message.
http://amatyr4n.com/codecanyon/fallr/

```
$.fallr('show', {
    content : '<p>Howdy.</p>'   // <--- in place of this I want to pass some id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fallr('show', {
    content : $("#someid").html()
});
```

Comment: Its a form, then form is not preserving values in next shown-up